# How to put a text input field in the GUI

Tags: operator

I'm working on a script that hides some objects by name (to simplify graphics of some high poly objects to switch them to bounding box while editing), and this is done by a python array matching which works well.

Now I'm about to write a GUI for this script and deleting strings from the array by pressing array of buttons works well, but I simply cannot add a text input field.

In an ideal case the array is saved besides the .blend file, but when a text is put in, some functions should be run (to delete element from the array), so a row.prop() doesn't seems to fit the task, I think I need an Operator, but these are all button-like.

I don't know the Blender GUI API too well, so any ideas where to search are welcomed.

Thanks in advance

PS now I have a code like this:

```
import bpy

samu_objects = ['leaves', 'IvyLeaf',]

def string_update (self, context):
    if self.items()[3][1] != "":
        samu_objects.append(self.items()[3][1])

bpy.types.Scene.my_string_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty (update = string_update,)

class SamuHide(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Samu Hide"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Samu"
    hidden = False

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        layout.row().operator("my.button")
        layout.row().prop(context.scene, "my_string_prop")
        if samu_objects:
            a = layout.box()
        for i in samu_objects:
            a.row().operator("my.button2", text=i,).text2=i

class Samu_Button(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.button"
    bl_label = "Hide objects"
    bl_description = "Hide certain objects"
    hidden = False     

    def execute(self, context):
        for o in [x for x in bpy.data.objects for y in samu_objects if x.name[:min([len(y), len(x.name)])] == y and len (x.name) >= len(y) ]:
            if SamuHide.hidden:
                o.draw_type='TEXTURED'
                o.hide_render = False
                o.show_name = False
            else:
                o.draw_type='BOUNDS'
                o.hide_render = True
                o.show_name = True
        SamuHide.hidden = not SamuHide.hidden
        self.report({'INFO'}, "teszt")
        return{'FINISHED'} 

class Samu_Button_2(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.button2"
    bl_label = ""
    #hidden = False
    text2  = bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        i = samu_objects.index(self.text2)
        self.report({'INFO'}, self.text2)
        del samu_objects[i]  
        return{'FINISHED'}

#++++++

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SamuHide)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Samu_Button)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Samu_Button_2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Samu_Button_2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Samu_Button)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SamuHide)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only for live edit.
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

Comment: If the property is a [StringProperty](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) the `layout.prop(...)` will display it as a text input.

Comment: Yes, but I either want to avoid the prop() or somehow want to associate a function that runs when there is input.

Comment: The [StringProperty](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) update method is called when its value is changed.  [Change FloatProp in example to StringProperty](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#update-example)

Comment: One more question:

When talking about array of buttons to delete strings (one button matches one string in a python list), is it the only way to put the buttons into the place by Operators (defining the button as an Operator and calling it with an operator() function), or is there a way to achieve it by a prop() call?